# Outer measure and a form of Borel-Cantelli Lemma

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

This is a simple problem involving the Borel-Cantelli lemma. Show that if $\sum \lambda^*(E_n)<\infty$ ($\lambda^*$ is the Lebesgue outer measure) then $\lambda^*(\liminf E_n)$ as well as $\lambda^*(\limsup E_n)$ are both zero.

**My solution:**
(for $\limsup$) We have:
$$
\limsup E_n = \bigcap_{n=1}^\infty \bigcup_{m=n}^\infty E_m 
$$
Thus
$$
\lambda^*(\limsup E_n) \leq \lambda^*\left(\bigcup_{m=n}^\infty E_m\right),\,\,\,\forall n \geq1
$$
For $\epsilon >0$ given, chose an $N \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $\sum_{m=N}^\infty \lambda^*(E_m) < \epsilon$, then:
$$
\lambda^*(\limsup E_n) \leq \lambda^*\left(\bigcup_{m=N}^\infty E_m\right)\leq \sum_{m=N}^\infty \lambda^*(E_m) < \epsilon
$$
Now how does a similar argument for $\liminf$ go? (I don't want to use the continuity of the Lebesgue measure as it has not been discussed yet in the book Im studying, only countable subadditivity)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Outer measure is monotone: $A \subseteq B$ implies $\lambda^{*} (A) \leq \lambda^{*} (B)$. Also, $\lim \inf E_n \subseteq \lim \sup E_n$. So $0\leq \lambda^{*} (\lim \inf E_n) \leq \lambda^{*}(\lim \sup E_n)=0$.